# Order Array by 2nd value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array as follows

```
Array
(
[1845267] => 2
[1845256] => 2
[1845260] => 2
[33636] => 1
[67376] => 2
[73250] => 1
[125313] => 2
[142062] => 1
[342520] => 2
[357301] => 2
[357303] => 1
[404419] => 1
[408957] => 1
[415891] => 2
[455894] => 1
[460119] => 1
[582332] => 1
[582333] => 1
[602886] => 1
)
```

My aim is to order them by the single digit value so the output would put the 2's(or highest number) to the top

```
Array
(
[1845267] => 2
[1845256] => 2
[1845260] => 2
[415891] => 2
[125313] => 2
[67376] => 2
[342520] => 2
[357301] => 2
[33636] => 1
[73250] => 1
[142062] => 1
[357303] => 1
[404419] => 1
[408957] => 1
[455894] => 1
[460119] => 1
[582332] => 1
[582333] => 1
[602886] => 1
)
```

Comment: FYI, thats not the "second value". That's the "value", and the big numbers, like `1845267`, are the "key"s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the [`arsort`](http://php.net/arsort) function:

> arsort — Sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association

Example:

```
arsort($array);
// done, $array is now sorted
```

Comment: I am using the system below to generate the array above, when I attempt to print_r(arsort($weights)); the output is simply the digit 1.                                                                     

    _$weights = array_count_values($weight);
    print_r(arsort($weights));_

Comment: arsort() doesn't return the array, it sorts the array *in place*. Do arsort($weights); print_r($weights);

Answer (score 1):

Built into PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

Answer (score 0):

bascially you need toh known array function for php [from here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php6p6.html)

and function as
      arsort($arr);

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
arsort($array)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php